# HTML Encoded Text via JS not rendering

Tags: javascript, html

I have a pair of triangles I wanted to include in a design which requires the text to be displayed via a JS file, but the HTML encoded text from the JS isn't rendering. Would anyone know how to make this work?

*Thanks for your time.*

Here's the specific Text:

> Websites ▴ Websites ▾

Here's the JS:
(Last line reads: Websites **&#9652** Websites **&#9662**)

```
$(function() {
  $(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Websites &#9652;" : "Websites &#9662;";
        });
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Does changing it to `$header.html(function() {...` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$header.text(function () {
    //change text based on condition
    return $content.is(":visible") ? "Websites &#9652;" : "Websites &#9662;";
});
```

to

```
$header.html($content.is(":visible") ? "Websites &#9652;" : "Websites &#9662;");
```

The `.text()` function is HTML escaped (again). Plus it doesn't take a function.